# Excel 2007 - Conditional Formatting: Font reverts to Cambria

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

Whenever I use conditional formatting the font changes to Cambria (size 10 or something). I can't change the font nor its size using the [home, conditional formatting, manage rules, edit rule, format, 'font'] tab. It's all greyed out! It looks like a bug? I've seen posts on this on the web but no answers. What now?

(Ps I'm using Windows XP SP2. We're going to upgrade to Windows 7 in a few months, which might make the problem go away.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be a little late, but I found this site when searching for a solution, so maybe someone else can benefit from the information.

Office 2010 also seems to disable Conditional Formatting while you have Tracking enabled. In my case, disabling tracking fixed the problem. You can then create the conditional formatting and re-enable tracking.

Hope this helps someone out!

G

Answer (score 2):

The way to fix this is :

- Open the conditional formatting window
- On the Font tab, click the button at the bottom right called Clear.
  This will remove all the settings on the Font tab - crucially,
  including the font itself, so that no font is selected at all.
- Then put back all of the other Font settings (like colour, italics
  etc) and then it will not change the font.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies... Since our PC upgrades I haven't been able to find where the old file was that gave the problem, so I cannot follow up on your answers .... But it seems you managed. Regards

Comment: This suggestion totally fixed my problem. Kudos.

Answer (score 1):

I have conditionally formatted some cells, and I have observed the behavior you describe. You can only change:

1. the font style (regular/italic/bold/bold italic)
2. whether it is underlined
3. the color.

I conditionally formatted the cells so that it turned red if the cell equals 10.

I later went back and changed the regular formatting of the cells so that they were all Arial 12 point. The cell with 10 remained red.

I don't think this is a bug, but rather a more subtle way to encourage you to make better font choices. You can underline it or turn it red, but it seems like Excel won't let you make it a 40 point Haettenschweiler.

---

Edit:
You mentioned that these were Excel 2003 spreadsheets that you are working with in Excel 2007. Have you been saving the spreadsheets in .xls or in .xlsx format? The inconsistent spreadsheet behavior you observe may be caused because Excel is trying to preserve Excel 2003 behavior. I recommend that you save it to Excel 2007 format (.xlsx) and see if the conditional formatting works better. (See comment trail for the full story.)

Comment: I just want it to be the same font as the rest of my worksheet, which is Arial 10. (I know the new default is Calibri 11 but many of my files were created in Excel 2003.)

Comment: Start by selecting the rows or columns that you want (by clicking on the number or letter). (Alternatively, you can choose the whole spreadsheet by clicking on the small triangle at the place where the rows and columns intersect, just above row 1 and to the just left of column A.) Right-click, format cells... go to the Font tab, and choose Arial and choose 10. By formatting the whole row, column, or worksheet, you get to pick your font and size. Conditional formatting does not allow font and size changes. I did this successfully with Excel 2007.

Comment: I know how to format cells. Please read my question, you don't understand it.

Comment: I read your question and I think I answered it: It's grayed out because you're not allowed to conditionally change it. It's not a bug. It's made that way to keep you from conditionally formatting cells to have different fonts or font sizes. Sometimes the answer to a question is, "No, you can't do that." It's not the answer you want to hear, but it *is* an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help- sorry if my answer sounded a bit terse. My point is: My other cells are arial. So the conditionally formatted cells should be arial too. Nothing else on my sheet is Cambria. I'm ok with not changing the font of the cells.

Comment: (Kudos for unruffling my feathers.) You're welcome. I started a new Excel 2007 spreadsheet, typed in some numbers in a column, and then duplicated the column. I changed column A to Arial (and left column B in Calibri). I conditionally formatted the cells in column A to underline the cell if it equaled 10. Excel underlined one cell *and left it in Arial*. Is that the behavior you are seeing? If not -- that is if your conditional change causes a change to Calibri -- then you might want to report your bug to http://answers.microsoft.com or http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft-office-2007 .

Comment: Here's another thought: I am wondering if you saved the spreadsheet in .xls or in .xlsx. Your inconsistent spreadsheet behavior may be caused because Excel is trying to preserve Excel 2003 behavior. I recommend that you save it to Excel 2007 format (.xlsx) and see if the conditional formatting works better.

Comment: (Apologies again! Mondays you know...) Interesting - you are correct, the file is .xls. (1) I saved it as .xlsx and now there is no problem.

Comment: (2) When I save it back to .xls, remove the conditional formatting, and add back the cond. form. again, it stays Arial. But after I then close the .xls file and open it again it is suddenly Cambria again.

Comment: (P.s. The default font for Office 2007 is Calibri, but this is Cambria.) I will report it to the sites you gave.

Ideally one would want to work in .xlsx / .xlsm of course always, but you often want to email files to people with older versions of Office. They should be able to open .xlsx I guess but I don't want to take the chance. Thanks!

Comment: @user630466, Glad it's working! I am going to post a separate answer in case anyone runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had the same exact problem. Thanks to this question (and the discussions in it),  some other research, and some random stabbing in the dark, I came to a 'solution'. It's not clean and exact and I can't explain it, but it worked for me. Hopefully, it is useful for others.

**Why Conditional Formatting is disabled**: To expand on one of rajah9's comments, the reason you can't change font in Conditional Formatting is discussed [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/font-and-size-disabled-conditional-formatting-t3695095.html) where it says:

> ...the reason behind disabling those
>   items for Conditional Formatting was
>   that they (MS) assumed that changing
>   attribute that would modify the column
>   width or row height should not be
>   allowed in CF.

Another user echoes [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/cant-change-font-conditional-formatting-t968340.html):

> ...Conditional formatting does not
>   support changing anything that might
>   change the overall format of the
>   worksheet. Changing the font could
>   result in data being cut off unless
>   the column is made wider because the
>   characters in the font might require
>   more space (as an example). Thus size
>   is not an option either.

So, you can't do it because MS doesn't trust you with it. That would be livable if it weren't for that fact that MS DOES change it.

Saving the spreadsheet in .xlsx would work, but some of us, myself included, have to support Excel 2003 users.

**My setup**: I am currently working with Excel 2010 with a .xls file that was created in Excel 2003. I noticed the conditional formatting formulas in one worksheet undesirably changed the font, while the other worksheet left it alone. This led me to believe that the desired behavior COULD be achieved.

**Solution**: I created a new worksheet. Then, I copied and pasted any borders, text, formulas, etc. from the old worksheet into the new one. Also, I redid any CFs I originally needed. Finally, I deleted the old worksheet, with the new, essentially identical one, in its place. The final result was all my CFs worked properly and didn't change the font!

This was all achieved in Excel 2010 and saved as the original .xls format. Every time I reopen the file after this change, my font remains intact.

As mentioned, I can't quite explain it, but it seems the old worksheet maintained something that caused this inconsistent behavior and recreating it in 2010 removed the hidden gremlin.

Comment: Hi belatedly, thanks for the feedback. (I forgot to activate my notifications). As you say, with a bit of effort one might get some results. Well I've migrated to Windows 7 + Excel 2010 now luckily! Regards

Comment: @Relaxed1 No problem. Glad to help out. Yea, there's quite a bit of hardship involved in working between different versions of Excel (even if they are using formats that SHOULD be compatible). Glad to hear it's not an issue for you and (from what I understand) you don't have to support the old .xls format.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old and possibly obsolete topic but it may still be handy for Excel 2003 users encountering this issue. In my case, I was using conditional formatting to color alternating rows based on `=mod(row(),2)=` `1` or `0`. Most of the time this worked fine but on one sheet, it was causing alternating rows to also have different size text (8 and 10 I believe).

When I went into the conditional formatting dialogue under font, the text size was greyed out as others have described. However, the Strikethrough option was checked. Unchecking this fixed the issue.

I'm not sure why this happened as I didn't use strikethrough anywhere in the workbook.

Answer (score 1):

I may have also found a "work-around".   I have a CF rule in place on an ".xls" sheet, but the returned font face is not at all what I want and I have not had this problem with my other rules.

So I tried this . . . . I left the CF rule in place for column B, then I chose column B again and used the "highlight cells rules" option -- instead of going straight to the "new rule" choice.

My choice was "text that contains".  I entered the text I am looking for in the first box, chose the "custom format" in the 2nd box.   I unclicked the Strikethrough check box (just to be safe) and chose the color I wanted.

I clicked OK, and the font face and size reverted to what the cell was originally formated for.

Don't really know why that worked, but VERY glad it did.

Comment: Hi thanks... When I created this topic originally I used the old Excel 2003 key sequence [alt, o, d] that is still supported by Excel 2007 and 2010, even though it doesn't appear in the ribbon. Probably a bad habit, but simply because I'm a more keyboard-orientated person and was used to the shortcut. I should of course rather type [alt, h, l, h] to navigate through the 2010 ribbon to 'highlight cell rules'. Will try it next time...

Answer (score 1):

In excel 2010 there is a clear formatting option under the font tab.  I cleared the format and it removed the default cambria that was set in my settings.  I was then able to modify the available options, but the grayed out font was then blank.

Answer (score 0):

I know this string is old, but I just HAD to write and tell:

- This is clearly a bug. Those who say different haven't read the whole context
- My experience is that the bug remains with both .xls and with .xlsx
- The question is not really whether you may change the font for the 
  conditional formatting.
- The question is that Excel suddenly thinks Cambria is a default 
  that cannot be changed and that looks very different from the Calibri.
- Changing the format for the whole spreadsheet has no affect at all as this
  is a bug assosiated with default format for the the outcome of 
  a condition of a cell.
- This is a bug assosiated with an init-state problem.

Solution:

- The above-mentioned "clear formatting" forces the code to the correct initial state. This solves the problem in my case
- For me this was the only way around, even though I had to manually do this for a certain cell and then copy the cell content to all cells that had inherited this bug.

Conclusion:

- It is a bug
- It remains as a follower from the init-state for the conditional formatting.
- Clear format might not work for everyone (reading the above) so I guess some people will have to re-do the programming on an unifected cell...

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be a belated answer but it's quite an easy one for anyone working in excel 2007 - I had this problem too where all I wanted to do was change the colour of the text but for some reason excel was also changing the font to Cambria.

In the conditional formatting/ edit rule dialogue box, I just pressed the 'clear' button in the bottom right corner which reverted the text to plain black with no bold/ italic etc. I then immediately reset my rule, applying a different colour and bold style, pressed OK and this then seemed to work. The text did not change to Cambria.

Hope this helps for anyone who is still having the problem.